# Determine Font Size After Autoshrink

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, font-size

I have 2 UILabels for a scorekeeping app (Home and Away).  The user can tap on Home or Away and change the label to be whatever they like.  This is all working fine.  When a user enters a name larger than the label size it will shrink the font to fit.  This makes the 2 labels no longer match in font size, and doesn't look right.  My question:  How can you set the font size of one label to the size of another label that has been "autoshrunk"?

I also realize I will need to write code to determine which font size is smaller between the two labels and set them both to that number.  I don't think I will have a problem with that, as long as I get an answer to the above question.  It seems like it should be simple, but it has so far eluded me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I hope you know the frame size of both the labels.

Use [– sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1619903-sizewithfont?language=objc) to find the minimum font size that it would use.

If you have any doubt, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, all working perfect now.  Don't know how I missed this method.

Comment: I'm looking for alternative since this has been deprecated in iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked fine:

```
- (CGFloat)actualTitleFontSize
{
    NSStringDrawingContext *labelContext = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
    labelContext.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2;

    NSAttributedString *attributedString =
        [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:label.text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : label.font}];
    [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:label.frame.size
                                   options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                   context:labelContext];

    CGFloat actualFontSize = label.font.pointSize * labelContext.actualScaleFactor;

    return actualFontSize;
}
```